# Need help finding the thevenin voltage across the diode. Is my work correct?

Tags: circuit-analysis, thevenin

[image]

I am admittedly really poorly versed in Thevenin's theorem and this is giving me a lot of trouble. I am having a hard time visualizing how to approach the problem, so any help would be appreciated.

Comment: To me, it doesn't seem as though you did anything wrong. You knew to dump the 16 k resistor -- correct, as the current source has infinite resistance and dominates it, obviously. You knew that the right side thevenin resistance was 14 k -- correct. You worked out the thevenin resistance on the left as 10 k || 20 k or about 6.7 k -- correct. You got the thevenin voltage on the left side correct. And you got the thevenin voltage on the right side correct. And you got the polarity with respect to the diode correct (antiwise.) Looks fine. You aren't confused.